Excel named range creation using xlwings workbook.names.add() generates extra quotes
Xlwings version: 0.30.14
When creating named range in excel 2016 using the following statement generates an extra quote. 
Does anyone have the same issue?
Here is my code
workbook.names.add(name, f"'{ws.name}'!{range_address}")

Here is the resulting named range
 ="'sheet1'!$C$22:$AL$999" <-- see the extra double quotes around it.

If I manually remove the quotes around it, then it works. like this
='sheet1'!$C$22:$AL$999

But the manual edit step defeats the purpose for the automation.

But you don't include the '=' in the range. Try changing it to workbook.names.add(name, f"='{ws.name}'!{range_address}")
